# Adding email signatures to web based emails automatically

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox-addon, client-side

I'm facing the challenge of adding email signatures automatically to web based emails.
When I say signature I mean the text at the bottom of the email body that identifies myself as the sender.

The ideal signature would be some HTML that would be predefined and stored somewhere else but plain text would be a good start also.

The challenge is to have a kind of pluggin that should detect the user is sending an email (maybe by parsing the url). Obviously this functionality would be restricted to certain browsers and email services since all of them are different.

But let's think for example of Firefox, IE and Chrome for internet browsers and GMail, Yahoo and MSN for web based email services.

I barely know about cliend side scripting, I'm a most server-side .net developer, which makes my task even more difficult.

If anybody has done something like this before, any help or clue would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Gonzalo

Comment: I think you can remove the quote around "Hacking" because this is pure hacking and a threat to privacy that every browser / website will try to block.  Can you tell more about your system?  Can't you just create a signature of your own?

Comment: Not really. Some client side javascript that injects a signature into the page DOM on the webmail sites doesn't really qualify as hacking. Addons like Better Gmail have done it for a long time. I think that's what he's going for.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. OP is looking for a Greasemonkey script.

Comment: @RandomEngy, well, I think I misunderstood... if the client is aware of the plugin, then it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really hacking. In Firefox it seems like the most obvious way to do it is a Greasemonkey script. You run some javascript on the page that's restricted to certain URLs. You look for the "send" button and inject some extra javascript to add your signature to the email text box before going out. Or you just have it add the signature to the email body text box when starting up, and assume the user will start typing above it. Probably other browsers have similar frameworks to Greasemonkey.

But a lot of web email services have built-in features to add a signature to your emails. It seems like using that natively would be a lot more robust and less error prone than meddling with the page with javascript every time you're trying to send an email.

But in any event, please use signatures responsibly. Keep them short and don't include information people already know from reading the email header.